# Boolean Algebra of size $2^{<\kappa}$ without an $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, boolean-algebras

For this post we work only with cardinals that live below the first measurable.

Assume that $\kappa$ is singular and $\kappa<2^{<\kappa}<2^\kappa$.

**Question:** Is it possible to have a Boolean Algebra (which is at least $\aleph_1$-complete) has of size $2^{<\kappa}$ and does not admits a non-principal $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter?

**Motivation:** Given a $\kappa$ I need a Boolean Algebra that does not admit a non-principal  $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter and the size of the Boolean Algebra is as small as possible.

In particular, the Boolean Algebra must be of size $<2^\kappa$, since the powerset of $\kappa$ provides the obvious example.

One obstacle is for $\kappa$ to be a weakly compact cardinal.

If $\kappa$ is a weakly compact cardinal then every $\kappa$-complete Boolean Algebra generated by $\kappa$-many sets admits a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter.

We can relax the completeness requirement as follows: $\kappa$ is $\delta$-weakly compact, if every $\kappa$-complete Boolean Algebra generated by $\kappa$-many sets admits a $\delta$-complete ultrafilter.

Since we live below the first measurable, it is not hard to show that $\aleph_1$-weakly compacts are just weakly compacts.

It follows that if $\kappa$ is a regular but not weakly compact cardinal, there exists a $\kappa$-complete Boolean Algebra generated by $\kappa$-many sets which does not admit an $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter. The size of such Boolean Algebra is $\kappa^{<\kappa}$.

If $\kappa$ is singular, then every $\kappa$-complete Boolean Algebra generated by $\kappa$-many sets has size $2^\kappa$. So, the above argument does not work anymore.